# How to add in PHP without causing the starting 0s to vanish

Tags: php

I have 2 php variables :

```
$oldnum = 00000497;
$newnum = 00002318;
```

when i do this `echo $oldnum + $newnum;` it gives me the value `2815` but i want value to come with initial 0s like this : `00002815`

Is there any way i can achieve this??

Comment: If they are numbers(integers) there is no leading zeros, so you would have to make them into text probably using `printf()` PS: Your 2 examples dont have leading zeros anywhere but in your head

Comment: Numbers prefixed with a zero are interpreted as _octal_, not decimal. There is not version of PHP where the code you have supposedly run will give you the answer you've quoted. Most will die with an error because 8 and 9 are not valid digits in octal. In short: Do not prefix decimal values with zeroes in your code.

Comment: That said, if these numbers are actually _strings_, then PHP will type-juggle them to integer as decimals if you try to do math on them. Leading zeroes are _never_ preserved on numeric types because there is no reason to. If you need leading zeroes, then you need a _string_, and Jim's answer is applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally, like any other scripting/programming language, PHP handles integers as integers. Any leading zeros are stripped away and not necessary.

Having leading zeros is meant for things like display or sorting, so only add them at the end, after you've manipulated the numbers to your liking, you convert to a string.

```php
$oldnum = 497;
$newnum = 2318;

// Apply math (addition, subtraction, powers, exponents, etc.)
$sum = $oldnum + $newnum;


// Done with math, now for display or sorting
echo str_pad($sum, 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
// 00002815
```